# Error executing Salesforce send: Number of results does not match number of SObjects;

Tags: integration, error, upsert

I'm getting this error when a Boomi integration attempts to upsert some custom object records into Salesforce.  The upsert is using an external ID as the key field (not sure if that helps clarify the issue).  I'm not sure what is causing it, or what it even means.  Here's the full text of the error I get:

> Error executing Salesforce send: Number of results does not match number of SObjects; Caused by: Number of results does not match number of SObjects

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's most likely a boomi specific error from their connector, did you by any chance discover what was the source of the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to the salesforce connector of boomi.
The cause that we found was that we didn't recieve a salesforce response for each record we had sent.
for example you upsert 5000 opportunities but salesforce only gives a response message back for 4999 records.

boomi documentation: https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2471#jive_content_id_Error_Error_executing_Salesforce_send_Number_of_results_does_not_match_number_of_SObjects_Caused_by_Number_of_results_does_not_match_number_of_SObjects

### Error: Error executing Salesforce send: Number of results does not match number of SObjects; Caused by: Number of results does not match number of SObjects

This is related to the Salesforce Operation's outbound actions.
Each Salesforce operation (Create, Update, Upsert, Delete and Merge) is configured differently, specific to the operation.

**For example:**
The Salesforce Delete action deletes an existing record in the Salesforce object defined in the Delete operation. You must supply the internal "ID" field in the request to delete the existing object record. If this internal ID is not readily available in your source data, consider using a Connector Call function to Query data based on a standard value such as Name.

For a Create action, it creates a new record in the Salesforce object defined in the Create operation. The internal "ID" field is generated automatically per each document sent to the operation.

Please refer to this link for more details.

https://community.boomi.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.boomi.com%2Fatomsphere%2FGUID-041CFAC6-48C6-4E23-ADE4-11B3967A5A44.html

Answer (score 0):

That error is caused when you specify a parameter in the connector but don't populate it.

Sometimes a person creates a parameter and then forgets to populate it.
Other times the person finds out it is not needed but forgets to delete it.